# PHP: extract name from string

Tags: php, string, strstr

I have a path that looks like:

`/home/duke/aa/servers/**servername**/var/...morefiles...`

With php, I want to extract the "servername" from the path

Unfortunately I'm not that well versed with php but I came up with something that used `strstr()` but I am only using PHP version 5.2 where as one of the parameter functions require 5.3

What could be some code that would return "servername"?

Comment: What do you mean by "extract" exactly? Do you know the server name? If not, what tells the server name apart from everything else?

Comment: there are a bunch of folders in /servers/ that represent servername. But my question is I want some function to return **servername**

Comment: Please show more examples of `...morefiles...`

Comment: Is the portion of the string before '\*\*servername\*\*' always the same ('/home/duke/aa/servers/'). If not, what variations are possible?

Comment: @George the portion of the string before servername is always the same

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use `explode('/', $path)` to break it down into the individual directories. After that, it's up to you to figure out which array element is the server name (with your sample path, it'd be #4):

```
$parts = explode('/', $path);
echo $parts[4]; // **servername**
```

Comment: Darn it, I didn't even think of that.

Comment: Wow I over looked explode too!

Answer (score 6):

```
function getServerName($data) {
    preg_match('#/servers/(.+)/var/#', $data, $result);
    if (isset($result[1]) {
        return $result[1];
    }
}

$data = '/home/duke/aa/servers/**servername**/var/...morefiles...';
echo getServerName($data);
```

Comment: will this working using `+` as the delimiter and having an unescaped `+` in the middle? I would guess you get an unknown modifier ')' error or something about not closing the group.

Comment: thanks this looks promising, I will try this out when I get home!

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '/home/duke/aa/servers/**servername**/var/...morefiles...';

echo preg_replace('$(.+)/servers/(.+)/var/(.+)$', '\2', $str);
```